# How to prevent Slack modal from closing while clicking outside the modal area

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

Just what the title says. I have a Slack modal flow that involves a lot of fields. Accidentally clicking outside the modal area causes the user to lose all the entered data.
How can I prevent this from happening?

I would like to prevent the modal from closing while clicking outside the modal body.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modal window is part of the Slack client application.

 Developers have no control on its behavior.

Comment: Ah, I don't have enough points to upvote your answer but it makes sense to me.